# Display 2 count results in Single Query

Tags: sql

I have an orders table and I want to display a report showing the Month, Total Orders and Total Orders rejected from the single table.

the table has dtcomplete, rtpID and supplierReject that i want to use, this nearly gets me there but there should only be 1 reject showing for January, I want the subquery to only check the grouped month

```
select datename(month, dtComplete) as Month, count(rtpID) as TotalOrders,
(select count(*) from RTPMaindetails where SupplierRejected = 1 and  datename(month, dtComplete) = datename(month, RTPMaindetails.dtComplete) group by datepart(month,dtcomplete) ) as Rejects
from RTPMaindetails
where datepart(year,dtComplete) = 2017 
group by datepart(month,dtcomplete),datename(month, dtComplete)
order by datepart(month,dtcomplete)
```

Shows:

```
Month    TotalOrders    Rejects
January    515             1
February   308             1
March      156             1
```

Should show

```
Month    TotalOrders    Rejects
January    515             1
February   308             0
March      156             0
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on what DBMS you're using, but most should support something like this:

```
select datename(month, dtComplete) as Month
     , count(rtpID) as TotalOrders,
     , count(case when SupplierRejected = 1 then rtpID end) as Rejects
  from RTPMaindetails
 where datepart(year,dtComplete) = 2017 
 group by datepart(month,dtcomplete),datename(month, dtComplete)
 order by datepart(month,dtcomplete)
```

Comment: works great, thanks, just another thought what is the best way to display the REJECTS as a percentage of the TotalOrders in the next column?

Comment: That definitely depends on the DBMS, but you could start with something like `count(case when supplierRejected = 1 then rptID end) * 100 / count(rtpID`).  Some databases may let you refer to previous columns by name instead of re-entering the expression to calculate them (or, you could probably get the same effect by wrapping the query as a subquery)

Answer (score 0):

you could do with a single query

```
select 
    datename(month, dtComplete) as Month
  , count(rtpID) as TotalOrders
  , sum( case when SupplierRejected = 1  then 1 else 0 ) as Rejects
from RTPMaindetails
where datepart(year,dtComplete) = 2017 
group by datepart(month,dtcomplete)
order by datepart(month,dtcomplete)
```